# Send more OBD PIDs @ same time

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm writing an Android App at the moment using the OBD2 System and I'd like to send more than one `OBD PID` at the same time to an `ELM327` Bluetooth Adapter.

Example:

```
010C/r
010D/r
```

Is this possible? I've tried it and I just got a HEX-response which changed its length everytime I tried it. So I couldn't interpret it.

At the moment I'm using a timer to send the PID "010C" for rpm to a thread every 1,5 seconds by using a timer, which is working. But I cannot send the request in a faster interval than 1,5 seconds.

```
rpmTimer = new Timer();
rpmTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
   public void run () {
      connectedThread.write("010C\r".getBytes());
   }
}, 500, 1500);
```

So has anyone managed to send two or more pids at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I was working with OBD a while back and had similar issues. As far as i know you can not send multiple PIDs at same time. I solved it by creating a queue of PIDs an sending them one after another when I got response from previous one and a bit of prediction what the next value should be in case of speed or something similar.

Unfortunately I do not have access to repository anymore so I can't tell you exactly how i solved it.

Comment: Ok I think I have a similar solution with my timer...do you remember how fast your obd stick respondet? Causo 1,5 seconds seem quite slow...and same days ago I tested the torque app and it looked like this app is able to read multiple pids at the same time

Comment: I think I got results around 1 second, something like that. For torque app I don't remember exactly what was the case, but it thing that they do not get results any faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try `010C0D\r`
Up to six PIDs can be requested in one query.